# MySQL - how to SHOW PROCESSLIST only with current user's processes?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way in MySQL 5 to show only the current user's processes(queries)?

The user has the `PROCESS` privilege, therefore `SHOW PROCESSLIST` displays running processes of all users. According to the documentation, `SHOW PROCESSLIST` does not allow any kind of `WHERE` syntax, nor did I manage to make it into a subquery.

Of course, I could simply send the query, e.g. in a PHP script, and go through the results in a loop, discarding everything that's not mine, but it seems rather inefficient. Changing the user privileges is not feasible.

Are there any other ways? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you use MySQL 5.1.7 or newer, you can use the [PROCESSLIST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/processlist-table.html) table in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.  So you can query it with ordinary `SELECT` queries and apply filtering conditions in a `WHERE` clause.

This feature is not implemented in MySQL 5.0 and prior.

Answer (score 5):

If the user does not have `PROCESS`, then `SHOW PROCESSLIST` will only show their own threads.